# Debug usb Asus Tinker Board with Android

Tags: android, adb

I flashed android nougat 7.1.2 on an Asus tinker board (downloaded from asus site) and i want to setup flutter development, so i need to connect the board/android-device to my host pc in order to setup adb (plus would be wifi adb but for 11 and lower still need to plug the cable to run "adb tcpip 5555"), but with a type-c-type-a usb cable nothing happens. If i plug a usb stick android recognize it and let me explore it. Is it possible to debug usb, even in an unconventional way?

Answer (score 1):

I have Asus Tinker Board S R2 and flashed Android 12 downloaded from Asus website. I can use wireless debugging without USB cable, hope this helps you.